# How to make an input on the keyboard shut down a batch program

Tags: batch-file, exit

How can I make a certain input on a keyboard shut down a batch program? I am a batch newbie and I'm having trouble exiting this program.

My program is made to start up a few other programs on the boot up of my computer. I know that if you hold Ctrl+C it will terminate the program but is there a way where it can shutdown instantly by pressing, for example, "f" on the keyboard?

Thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: You could write a DLL that calls GetAsyncKeyState, then do RunDLL32 in batch to call its function. I can help you out if you want.

Comment: Can you dumb this down a bit?

Comment: Okay. Just hold on for a bit and I'll post up a solution :)

Comment: ALT+F4? That won't work why?

Comment: Because it opens a command prompt that opens other programs. The command prompt would continue to open the programs until they are no longer being shut down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution time!

I made a simple EXE that sets the `ERRORLEVEL` value in the batch file to 1 when the specified key is pressed.

So if you did

```
GetKeyDoodle J
if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo You pressed J!
```

And the user pressed J or is holding J, it should echo. Here's the download to the `GetKeyDoodle`

[GetKeyDoodle](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/33727415/GetKeyDoodle.exe)

[Test.Bat](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/33727415/test.bat)

Comment: @user2058124 You're welcome. If it worked for you, hit the outline of a checkmark to accept.

Comment: works great! here is my code:

@echo off
:start
start cmd
GetKeyDoodle F
if ERRORLEVEL 1 exit
goto start


ill edit what it starts obviously